# Building a blog-like app with django, should I normalize images outside of the blog entry's model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Just wondering because at the moment I am keeping the ImageFields as part of the BlogPost model. If I want to support the potential for 20 images, I have 20 such fields, when often almost 19 of them will never be used. But if I normalize them into a separate model, it's not as intuitive to add images to a post in the admin page, since you have to select the post from a drop down for each image you wish to add, over and over.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Well, having 19 unused image fields in almost every post seems like the wrong solution to me...

Comment: Yes, agreed, and that's why I've posted. But I also don't want users to have to, after posting the blog post itself, go and add images one at a time, and for each image find in an eventually huge drop down field the post they just created. Seems quite error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should create separate model for images.

To edit the images in the admin site you should use inlines. Read the docs here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: This takes care of pulling in the form for adding the image, but if the image is bound to the post, don't we have a chicken before the egg problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what do you mean. You will be able to add, as well as edit/delete the image via editing the post instance in admin site.

Answer (score 1):

There are already-built image-handling modules for django. For example:

http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/

http://code.google.com/p/django-fleshin/

Comment: Looks promising, but definitely overkill for what I need.